# Windows Universal App HubSection Change Page.BottomAppBar

Tags: navigation, win-universal-app

I am developing WP 8.1 App and am using a   Now based on the hubsection the user is viewing I want to change the Page.BottomAppBar.  How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all use hubsection viewchanged method

```
hubname_SectionsInViewChanged(object sender, SectionsInViewChangedEventArgs e) 

{

    //Get current hub section
     var section = HubPlanListsTeams.SectionsInView[0];
     var hubname = section.Name.ToString();

                    if (hubname.Equals("Section1"))
                    {
                      //  Set programatically bottombar for section1 hubsection 
                    }
                     else if(hubname.Equals("Section2"))
                    {
                     //Set  programatically bottombar for Section2 hubsection 
                     }

}
```